# How to clear completely the data in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I use Vuetify/Vue/Vuex in an application, with many companies which has many projects.

A user can switch from one company to another:

```
export const setCompany = ({ commit, dispatch }, id) => {
    dispatch('resetData').then(function (){
        return axios.post(`/api/setCompany/${id}`).then((response) => {
            location.href = 'https://example.com/#/dashboard'
            location.reload()
        })
    })
}

export const resetData = ({ dispatch,commit }) => {
    commit('projects/SET_PROJECTS_DATA', [], {root: true})
    commit('projects/SET_PROJECT_DATA', [], {root: true})
    commit('issues/SET_ISSUES_DATA', [], {root: true})
    commit('issues/SET_ISSUE_DATA', [], {root: true})
    commit('todos/SET_TODOS_DATA', [], {root: true})
    commit('todos/SET_TODO_DATA', [], {root: true})
    commit('potentials/SET_POTENTIALS_DATA', [], {root: true})
    commit('potentials/SET_POTENTIAL_DATA', [], {root: true})
}
```

When I work on the 'old' company, I have a list of projects from this company.

When I switch to the new company, I still have the same projects (from the old company). The list of projects is not cleaned with the reload.

I tried to check the vuex state 'projects/project' and 'projects/projects' after reload. These vars is empty. But in the list of projects, the projects of the previous company still appears.

Where I have to clean the data to have an empty project list?

Comment: `resetData` looks fine for me. why not calling it when changing companies?

Comment: @Deniz I call it, and when I check after (comment the location.href and comment location reload()) the state of 'projects/projects` is empty. Also after the reload of the page. But I don't know why, the list of projects is still there...

Comment: when switching companies are you using the same stored `projects` data from store?

Comment: Yes I call the same data. But I thought, with resetData i will clear it.

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

I do use this solution: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1118#issuecomment-356286218

You can look for a lot of possible ways to do this in the github thread actually.

```js
function initialState () {
  return { /* .. initial state ... */ }
}

export default {
  state: initialState,

  mutations: {
    reset (state) {
      // acquire initial state
      const s = initialState()
      Object.keys(s).forEach(key => {
        state[key] = s[key]
      })
    }
  }
}
```

You also have this solution: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-completely-reset-the-vuex-store/13611/5